# Weird "Unkown Error" message at specific times

Tags: system-error, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

i get this weird "Unknown error" message sometime every 56th minute of every hour. The error looks like this:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

It used to pop at every 26th minute but recently moved to every 56th. Anyone got any ideas as to what this may be?

Comment: See if these two comments help: ['Authorization Failed' toast message at startup](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/160003) && ['Authorization Failed' toast message at startup](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/160004)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an app installed on the phone, that **has a 1 hour sync interval** which fails to connect to its designated server. The sync will land on the same minute of every hour.

**Things to try:**

- Find a connected account with a 1 hour sync interval set, by going to `Settings -> Account & Sync`. Remove or update the culprit through Play Store.
- If you have **DroidWall or AFWall** on a rooted device, the culprit app might be blocked in the iptables rules.
- Try **connecting to a different network**, the network you're currently on may have a firewall blocking the culprit app. If you're on cellular data (no WiFi), still try this, your provider may have a screwed up DNS record for the culprit site.
- **Update every app** on your phone through Google Play Store, especially if you're on Marshmallow.
- If all the above fails, disable one app at a time until you find the culprit. You may not be able to disable updated apps, only uninstall them. You will have to use `pm disable com.example.application` from ADB or a terminal emulator. When you find the app, uninstall it, or contact the developer for an update.

**If you're rooted and have Xposed framework:**

- There are two Xposed mods that will tell you directly what app the error is originating from:

  1. **[Buttered Toast - Xposed Repo](http://repo.xposed.info/module/ca.gabrielcastro.butteredtoast)**: Adds the Application name to any Toast notification displayed.
  2. **[Burnt Toast](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.burnttoast)**: Inspired by Buttered Toast, Burnt Toast shows the application icon in a Toast message. Screenshot:

[image: Burnt Toast Xposed]

I wouldn't recommend Burnt Toast in this case because not all apps have distinct icons, but it is more UI-friendly.

Hope this helps

Comment: i only have trusted apps installed so this is most likely a bug/outdated so regardless if i find the cause or not it shouldnt be a concern? is there a chance of this being a system problem where the android OS itself is trying to sync somewhere maybe caused by a failed update? is there a way to check the integrity of the OS for corrupt files and such? thanks for the quick answer by the way, im gonna do what you suggested and see if it resolves itself.

Comment: This is not a virus, although the nature of the toast notification does make one paranoid because it doesn't say what app it originates from. It also isn't an OS integrity issue, or a failed update. I've had failed updates in the past, it will ask you with a date picker when to download the update again. If your Google account sync was having problems it will show a sign-in screen, or a persistent "sync failed" notification. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Uh, `pm disable` requires root access. You didn't mention it explicitly.

Comment: thanks, i went through the apps and found out that it was facebook messenger that was causing the issue. thanks!